# apache camel simple language test on null exchange in Bluepring XML not working

Tags: java, null, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.17 and using the simple language to catch a null exchange.  It is not working and I've tried several formatting approaches, but it doesn't catch a null.  I believe it is the format/syntax of how I'm using it.  please instruct where I'm going wrong.  thank you!

```
<process id="_process18" ref="csvMarshallerProcessor"/>
<process id="toReOrgCSV" ref="reOrgCSVData"/>
<choice id="_choice13">
    <when id="_when13">
        <simple>"${body}" == null</simple>
        <log id="_log22" message="body is NULL, do not send NULL body!"/>
        <stop id="_stop7"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
```

I've tried

```
<simple>"${body} == null"</simple>
<simple>"${body}" == null</simple>
<simple>${body} == null</simple>
<simple>${body} == 'null'</simple>
```

I set the exchange to null in a previous process IF the data is filtered out and ineligiable to send out.  I'd like to just use Camel Spring XML.

???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the `exchange` as null, as that is not valid, set the message body to null or empty string etc.

```
exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
```

And then you can use simple to test its null,

```
${body} == null
```

Or if you set it as empty text

```
${body} == ''
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you Claus!

this is what I ended up with, ..

```
...
    line.append(System.lineSeparator());

    if ( lookup ) {
        if ( validate(fleetName, line.toString()) ) {
            baos.write(line.toString().getBytes());
        }
    } else {
            baos.write(line.toString().getBytes());
    }
 }
    List<String> serviceRecords = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(baos.toString().split(System.lineSeparator())));

    if ( serviceRecords.size() > 1 ) {  //has more than a header
        byte[] ba = baos.toByteArray();
        exchange.getIn().setBody(ba);
    } else {
        exchange.getIn().setBody(null);  //empty message, only header, no data
    }

Camel Context
    <process id="_process18" ref="csvMarshallerProcessor"/>
    <choice id="_choice13">
        <when id="_when13">
            <simple trim="true">"${body}" == "" || ${body} == null</simple>
            <log id="_log22" message="body is NULL, do not send NULL body!"/>
            <stop id="_stop7"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
            <process id="toReOrgCSV" ref="reOrgCSVData"/>
            <to id="_to7" uri="{{DDFEndpoint}}?fileName={{APMLoaderPath}}/${header.aircraftMetadata.shipNumber}-${header.enginePosition}_${header.messageDateTime}.csv"/>
            <log id="_log23" message="Sending data packet: ${header.aircraftMetadata.outputPath}/${header.aircraftMetadata.shipNumber}-${header.enginePosition}_${header.messageDateTime}.csv"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</aggregate>
```